# discovering merged git branches on repositories that use squash by default?

Tags: git, github

If i have a local git branch called `feature1` with a couple commits. I create a github PR and merge it.

If the repository is **not** using the awful [github's squash merge](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-request-merges)*, i am able to use after updating my `master`/`main` branch:

```
git branch --merged
* main
feature1
```

To easily see which of my feature branches are already merged in the up-to-date main/master branch.

Now, if the github repository is doing Squashed merges, how do I figure out programatically if a branch was merged into `master`/`main` or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really possible in the full general case, but you may not care about that for two reasons:

- GitHub do not provide the full general case.
- Some of those full general cases amount to nitpicking anyway.

So this gives us two ways to handwave away the hard cases, with the first one probably being the most important.  What you will get, once you write a program to do this, is a program that probably works *well enough* for all the cases you care about and will ever encounter.

There is not, however, any pre-written solution you can just *use*, as far as I know.  You will have to write your own program—perhaps a simple shell script.  (I started on one once, but I haven't ever gone back to fix it up.  Some cases get tricky.)

When someone uses either the <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd> or <kbd>SQUASH AND MERGE</kbd> button on GitHub, they add, to their GitHub repository, either a single commit—<kbd>SQUASH AND MERGE</kbd>—or multiple commits with <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd>.  There are some distinguishing features about these commits, so that after you `git fetch` *their* commits from *their* repository, you can compare these commits to *your* commits on your `feature` branch:

- First, and perhaps most important, every one of these commits can be generated mechanically by Git itself, by running either `git rebase` or `git merge --squash`: such a command will run to completion, without merge conflicts.  This means you can do the same thing in your own Git repository, and see if it works and produces the same source snapshot.
- Second, if they've used <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd>, there will be a one-to-one correspondence between each of their commits and the commits that your own Git will copy when you run a no-interaction rebase in your own repository.  If they've used <kbd>SQUASH AND MERGE</kbd> there won't be and you'll want to run a no-interaction `git merge --squash` in your own repository, to see if you get the same source snapshot without conflicts.

If we make some often-but-not-always true simplifying assumptions, we can do the checking without actually running `git rebase` or `git merge --squash`.  This is particularly helpful for the rebase case because there are multiple different ways to run rebase, each of which has slightly different pitfalls, and it's not clear to me, at least, which of these methods GitHub use (or they may have cobbled together their own non-interactive conflict-detecting equivalent using `git cherry-pick`).

The biggest simplification is this one.  **If** we have the same starting point that they do, *then* each copied commit, or the single squashed commit, will produce the same source snapshot we have in each of our commits, or at the tip of our `feature` branch.  That is, suppose we make a PR when we have this state:

```
...--o--o--*   <-- remote/main
            \
             A--B--C   <-- our-feature
```

They use either of those two annoying modes that *copies* our commits, so that the hash IDs don't match, or squashes (same effect).  We fetch their new commits into our own repository, and we now have either:

```
...--o--o--*--ABC   <-- remote/main
            \
             A--B--C   <-- our-feature
```

or:

```
...--o--o--*--A'-B'-C'  <-- remote/main
            \
             A--B--C   <-- our-feature
```

In both of these cases, the tip commit of their branch—our `remote/main` commit, which is either `ABC` or `C'`—has the *same source snapshot* as our commit `C` at the tip of our `feature`.  So:

```
git rev-parse remote/main^{tree}
```

and:

```
git rev-parse feature^{tree}
```

will produce the *same hash ID*.

This particular simplification breaks down when they start from a commit that isn't the tip of ours, so that they have:

```
...--o--o--*--X--ABC   <-- main
```

in their repository for instance.  Now their `ABC` squash commit doesn't match our `C` commit because of the extra `X` commit.  It *does* hold, but becomes harder to *test*, if they do this:

```
...--o--o--*--ABC--X   <-- main
```

because now we have to find commit `ABC` by working backwards from the tip of our `remote/main` after we fetch the `ABC-X` chain and add it to our own repository.

For the "breaks down" case, we really have to reproduce the action that GitHub took so that we can test whether the source snapshot matches what Git can mechanically produce on its own (if anything).  This requires enumerating all the new-to-us commits after a `git fetch` operation, so it gets messy.

Comment: In those examples, how do I know which of the many Squashed merges i receive when I pull the new main/mater, is the ABC of my A,B,C? It's a large project, with many merges every hour.

Comment: That's another problem. You see a new commit `S`: how do you know which branch it represents? Given the drawing you've made, one way would be to see if the snapshot *in* `S` is exactly the same as the snapshot in `C`, `F`, or `I`. If so, `S` represents a squash of that commit. But if `S` has another commit after `M` before `S`, this method won't work.

Comment: Ultimately, this is a hard problem. That's why I say that for *this one specific case* it's not so bad, but in general, it's much harder. If someone squashed in `branch3`, you should just delete `branch1` and `branch2`, perhaps. (A better way to deal with this is to stop using `git merge --squash` at all, in which case the entire problem vanishes.)

Comment: Note that if commits `A-B-C` are logically sensible on their own, and if a bug is later discovered, it may be easier to *fix* the bug (and find it with `git bisect`) if commits `A-B-C` remain separate commits. That's another argument *against* using `git merge --squash`. But of course if this is a big project with many contributors, getting everyone to agree to a process improvement can be difficult.

Comment: oh, don't try to sell me on the benefits of not-squashing... i loath squashing! IMO serves nothing but as a signal that developers on that project do not care (or understand) how to properly construct a meaningful git commit :(  ...back on topic, your comments are very helpful. i might be able to try to hack something using the remote branch deletions that happens after someone merge/delete branch on github, assuming i don't push with a name change, it should work out.